# Formatting the T-SQL ResultSet

Tags: t-sql

H All,

I have following ResultSet generated by some 3-4 queries in T-Sql. The result looks something like this:

**Month        Payment**
*January       200*
*February      200*
*March         200*
*April         200*
*june          200*
*July          200*
*August        200*
*September     200*
*October       200*
*November      200*
*December      200*

Now, depending on userdefined value, lets say 4, I need to arrange them some like this.

**Month                            Payment**
*January;Febrary;March;April       200*
*May;June;july;August              200*
............. so on.

If the user has chosen for 3, then,

**Month                            Payment**
*January;Febrary;March       200*
*April;May;June              200*
............. so on.

How do I do this? Any suggestions? 
Thanks in Advance!!
:))

Comment: SQL Server handles the data - formatting like this should be handled by your front-end application or your report writer....

Comment: Hi Derek Kromm,
I have accepted only those questions whose answers have given me some clue to sort my issues. 

I hope you also dont want me to up vote the answers which are of no use.

I am using Sql SERVER 2008.

Comment: Hi  marc_s,
Don't mind but I dont agree to this. Sql Server is compatible enough to handle these small formatting issues.

Comment: will the payment always be the same ?

Comment: @Raj: databases generally are not supposed to do formatting tasks - you say its a 'small' formatting task, but where is the line? To keep things simple, you should just do it in your presentation layer.

Comment: Hi M.R. I have got the answer in "t-clausen.dk"'s comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly don't know how to handle payment since you have not described it, here is a way of solving it with recusive sql

```
declare @t table([Month] varchar(12), Payment int)
declare @uservalue int
set  @uservalue = 3
insert @t values('January',200)
insert @t values('February', 200)
insert @t values(' March', 200)
insert @t values('April', 200)
insert @t values('May', 200)
insert @t values('June', 200)
insert @t values('July', 200)
insert @t values('August', 200)
insert @t values('September', 200)
insert @t values('October', 200)
insert @t values('November', 200)
insert @t values('December', 200)

;with a as(
select month, payment, rn = row_number() over (order by (select 1))
from @t
), b as
(
select cast(month as varchar(200)) month, payment, rn
from a where (rn - 1) % @uservalue = 0
union all
select cast(b.month +';'+ a.month as varchar(200)), a.payment, a.rn
from b join a on a.rn - 1 = b.rn and b.rn %@uservalue > 0
)
select month, payment from b where rn % @uservalue = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an xml solution

```
declare @t table([Month] varchar(12), Payment int)
declare @uservalue int
set  @uservalue = 3
insert @t values('January',200)
insert @t values('February', 200)
insert @t values(' March', 200)
insert @t values('April', 200)
insert @t values('May', 200)
insert @t values('June', 200)
insert @t values('July', 200)
insert @t values('August', 200)
insert @t values('September', 200)
insert @t values('October', 200)
insert @t values('November', 200)
insert @t values('December', 200)

;WITH x AS ( select payment, rn = (row_number() over(order by (select 1)) - 1)/@uservalue, month
FROM @t
) 
SELECT REPLACE(STUFF(( 
SELECT ',' + [month] 
FROM x t 
WHERE t.rn = x.rn
for xml path(''), type 
).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''), ',', ' ') [month], payment FROM x
GROUP BY rn, payment
```